# debug assertion failed: dbgheap.cpp and dbgdell.cpp

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, destructor

I have a some kind of memory leak problem. I had it in earlier lines, but i corrected it by writing a copy assignment constructor. But the problem is on the `delete newB` line. When i comment out that line, there is another error popping out. Where do you think i have some memory leaks because i know it is somehow related with the memory allocation.

```
void BankingSystem::addBranch(const int id, const string name){
    if(isBranchExisting(id)){
        cout << "\n\tBranch " << id << " already exists. Please try it with another id number.";
    }
    else if(!isBranchExisting(id)){
        Branch* tempArray = new Branch[cntBranches];
        if(cntBranches != 0){
            for(int i = 0; i<cntBranches; i++){
                tempArray[i] = allBranches[i];
                }


            delete[] allBranches;

            allBranches = new Branch[cntBranches+1];
            for(int i = 0; i<cntBranches; i++){
                allBranches[i] = tempArray[i];
            }

            allBranches[cntBranches] = Branch(id, name);
            delete[] tempArray;
        }
        Branch* newB = new Branch(id,name);
        allBranches[cntBranches] = *newB;
        cout << "\n\tBranch " << id << " is added successfully.";
        delete newB;
        cntBranches++;
    }
}
```

I can show you the Branch class too if you need it because it may be related with constructors or destructor too, but i was not successful at correcting those as this error continues to pop out.

Edit: Sorry, i thought i stated it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It fails because  initially cntBranches==0 and allBranches is uninitialised, as I assume.  
Thus when first time call addBranch  
allBranches[cntBranches] = *newB; 
will write into some random memory location pointed by garbage in allBranches. 
Thru rest of pointer manipulations are incorrect and will lead to errors as well. For example  
delete[] tempArray;  
will delete everything that was allocated previously leaving allBranches pointing to deleted objects. So I'd suggest either read more about what pointer is and how mem allocation works, or use std::vector if possible.

Comment: firstly, I initialize it in constructor.

`BankingSystem::BankingSystem(){
 allBranches = new Branch[1];
 allCustomers = new Customer[1];
 allAccounts = new Account[1];
 cntBranches = 0;
 cntCustomers = 0;
 cntAccounts = 0;
 nextAccountId = 1000;
}`

I thought i copied them into allBranches[]in for loop. I watched a lot videos about it, also read some, but still can't manage it.

Comment: allBranches[i] = tempArray[i]; here you will overwrite all newly created by allBranches = new Branch[cntBranches+1]; branches making them leaked memory and after that with delete[] tempArray; you will delete everything useful that was in allBranches since tempArray still holds pointers to previously created data and will delete them. And still all of this code can be replaced with just one line  allBranches.push_back(Branch(id, name)); with allBranches being std::vector<Branch>

Comment: so what is the difference between  
`for(int i = 0; i<cntBranches; i++){  
                allBranches[i] = tempArray[i];  
            }`  
and  
`for(int i = 0; i<cntBranches; i++){  
 allBranches[i] = *new Branch(tempArray[i]);  
   }`  
in terms of memory?

Comment: Well this is a bit better since you will create yet another copy of Branch(at a different address) that won't be deleted later with tempArray. Thru it still will overwrite already existing object that was created with Branch* tempArray = new Branch[cntBranches]; and lead to mem leak.

Comment: So what should i do to prevent overwriting? I will read more sources about it tonight, but still i am searching some answers for my specific questions.

Comment: First you really need to understand what pointer is how it works, what is allocation and deallocation. For the code you provided answer would be rewrite it in correct way from scratch.

Comment: Also i forgot to mention that i have a copy assignment operator. 

`Branch& Branch::operator= (const Branch &bRight){
 branchId = bRight.branchId;
 branchName = bRight.branchName;
 numOwnedAccounts = bRight.numOwnedAccounts;
 ownedAccounts = bRight.ownedAccounts;
 return *this;
}`